# Pandas - Using value from a column as an index to extract value from an existing column into a new column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The `Datframe`is shown below. i'd like to add another column 'newcol' which uses the value in the 'price' column to look-up the position in the 'name' column.

```
     name  price stock
1  orange     2   Yes
2  banana     3    No
3  lemon      7   Yes
4  mango     21    No
5  apple     11   Yes
```

output

```
     name  price stock newcol
1  orange     2   Yes  banana
2  banana     3    No  lemon
3  lemon      7   Yes
4  mango     21    No
5  apple     11   Yes
```

M code is obviously wrong

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name':
    ['orange','banana','lemon','mango','apple'],
    'price':
    [2,3,7,21,11],
    'stock':
    ['Yes','No','Yes','No','Yes']
})


print(df)

df['newcol'] = df['name'].iloc[df['price'].iloc[df['price'].index]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['newcol'] = df.loc[df['price'], 'name'].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: I get the following error "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported..."

Comment: Does your price column contain numbers that your index doesn't?

Comment: `df.index.isin(df.price).any()` should tell you.

Comment: yes, there are numbers in the price column which are not present in the index column